# How to add multiple object on my doc on firestore with react native?

Tags: ios, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have my collection, on my collection i have an array and on this array i wanna add a multiple object.

With my method i can add only one object and i would like to add differents objects on my array

this is my method :

```
 async function RegisterTeam () {
        // User is signed in.
        firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(await AsyncStorage.getItem ('userID'))
    .update({
        "MyTeam.newTeamObj":[{
            Activity:activity,
            City:city,
            Adress:adress,
            text: text,
            members: members,


        Owner:true
        }]
  
        })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('team created !')
                
            
            })         
        }
```

This is my model :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

would you like to give more objects into the array, or different object to the newTeaObj property?

```
.update({ myTeam: firestore.FieldValue.ArrayUnion(data) })
```

or

```
const prevData = [...myTeam]

    .udapte({ myTeam: [...prevData, ...newObject]})
```

or you can use subcollections.

Comment: different object to the array, the goal is to be able to create different team on "myTeam"

Comment: you need to inject more elements into the array?

Comment: yes i need to have for example MyTeam :
                                                        newTeamObj1 : {}
                                                        newTeamObje2: {}

Comment: so you need MyTeam as an array, then the object i think, if right then u have to much nested arrays.

Comment: even if i take off newTeamObject and i put just "MyTeam":{} i don't know how to add a few team on this object

Comment: i update on of your solution and i have undefined is not a function

Comment: use firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data), https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue